# How to create new resource with foreign key in TastyPie

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I'm still new to tastypie, but it seems like a really neat library. Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulties with it.

I have two models, and two resources associated with those models:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    pass

class ContainerItem(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Container', related_name='items')

# For testing purposes only
class ContainerResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Container.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()

class ContainerItemResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = ContainerItem.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

I have created a `Container` object via jQuery:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({});

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/container/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false
});
```

However, when I go to create a `ContainerItem`, I get this error:

```
container_id may not be NULL
```

So my question is: **How do I create a new resource when there is a ForeignKey relationship?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ForeignKey relationships are not represented automatically on the ModelResource. You'll have to specify:

```
blog = tastypie.fields.ForeignKey(ContainerResource, 'blog')
```

on the `ContainerItemResource`, and then you can post the resource uri of the container when you post up the container item.

```
var containeritemData = {"blog": "/api/v1/container/1/"}
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/containeritem/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: containeritemData,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false
});
```

For more info, check out these links:

In this section, there is an example of how to create basic resources. Toward the bottom, they mention that relationship fields are not automatically created through introspection:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-resources

Here they add an example of creating a relationship field:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-more-resources

Here is a blurb about adding reverse relations:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships

All [the docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) are good if you read them like a novel, but it can be hard to find specific things among them.

Comment: Hi dokkaebi. This looks like the solution, but where can I read more on this?

Comment: I know this answer is pretty old, and my question is slightly off-topic, but does tastypie also have something that when you `GET` a resource and you have a foreign key, instead of the foreign resource URL you get the actual object?

Comment: @EduardLuca You can specify `full=True` on the foreign key field definition.

Comment: does it have to be URI? i want fk represented as id on POST